# nginx + node app + vuejs app

Tags: nginx, node.js

I'm trying to setup a nginx config to try to achieve this:

- I have a nodejs app, which serves the public part, in a server running in localhost in port 3000.
- I have a vuejs spa app, which serves the "admin" part of the app, in a server running in localhost in port 8000.

What I am trying to achieve, is to have a nginx acting as a reverse proxy to proxify all requests to `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/*` to the nodejs app and all requests to `http://localhost:8080/admin` to my vuejs app. For this I have made up a nginx config file like this:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /admin/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_store off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_store off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the admin part is not working, because when I access `localhost:8080/admin/` the initial html template is being traversed with a `<script src="/app.js"></script>`, so this tries to load `localhost:8080/app.js` which doesn't work, obviously.
I have tried to set a `<base href="/admin">` tag in the admin site but it is not working. It keeps trying to load `localhost:8080/app.js`, instead of `localhost:8080/admin/app.js` (this url works fine).

What should I do to make this config work?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to set  `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/; `

Comment: Yes, sorry, I also tried it.

Comment: Can you try

`rewrite ^/admin/(.*) /$1 break;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/$uri$is_args$args;`

Comment: Nothing. It is still trying to request `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.js` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app.js` -_-

Comment: This must be something with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/index.html` with the script tag `<script src="/app.js"></script>`, I think, but I cannot change that because it is auto-injected. Maybe I should try to just serve the statics with nginx `root` directive and production and keep on accessing `http://localhost:8000` in development instead of serving everything with nginx, but for development It would be nice to have the same env as in production.